# Logical error on assigning a char to a multidimensional char array on C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to set up a board for a player to put characters on, for this example, I just use 'R'. But when the player enters the character and the program displays the board, no change occurs. I don't know what's wrong so far and I am looking for some light on this.

I should say that this was a very easy thing to do on Python but I just moved onto C++ and the learning curve is steep.

Here is the code:

```
char matrix[9][9];

void doBoard()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
            if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') || (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
            {
                matrix[i][j] = '_';
                std::cout << '|' << matrix[i][j] << '|';
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


void pickR()
{
    int column;
    int row;
    std::cout << "\nThe columns and rows are enumerated from 1 to 10.\n";
    std::cout << "Select the column and row where you would like to set your piece.\n";
    std::cout << "Column (1-10): ";
    std::cin >> column;
    std::cout << "Row (1-10): ";
    std::cin >> row;
    matrix[column - 1][row - 1] = 'R';
    std::cout << matrix[column][row] << "\n";

main()
{
doboard();
pickR();
doboard();
return 0;
}
```

After running this code when the board reappears on the screen, all of the characters are still '_', nothing changes.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: `doboard;`, `pickR;`?? Better `doboard();` and `pickR();`

Comment: Please get used to C/C++ ranges: They start with zero and end at size-1 (your loops are wrong, also the size of the matrix)

Comment: @RedRoboHood [Yup!](http://ideone.com/uWiH9g) Voted to close.

Comment: I did not add all of the code, just the part where I have a problem on. Forgot the brackets, I had to translate and retype the code from the editor because it was in another language, sorry.

Comment: @andross If that `doBoard` function is supposed to set the entire board to `_`, why do an `if` statement?  Just set the position to `_`, regardless of what's in that location.  Or maybe you should tell us the goal of that function.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are some *syntax* error which you can get rid of after knowing the C++ syntax well, but your logical error is that:

```
char matrix[9][9];
```

Remember, C++ use zero indexing.

So, `matrix` is a 2D array, has column index `0-8` and row index `0-8`, hence the following loops can give you undefined behavior,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') || (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
```

So rewrite them,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') || (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
```

For the following line,

```
if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') || (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
```

say `matrix[i][j]` contains `R`, then `matrix[i][j] != 'R'` will be *false* but `matrix[i][j] != 'O'` will be `true`. Hence the `if` block will executed and replace the `R` with `_` which you don't expect. That's why use `&&` *AND* instead of `||` *OR*.

Instead of

```
if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') || (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';
        std::cout << '|' << matrix[i][j] << '|';
    }
```

Use,

```
 if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') && (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';
    }
    std::cout << '|' << matrix[i][j] << '|';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same problem that when I call doBoard(); for the second time, the characters don't change from '_' to 'R'.

Comment: @andross Why do you expect `doBoard` to change underscores to 'R'?   Where in that function do you set any position to an 'R'?  Maybe tell us the goal of that function, since that `if` statement looks awfully suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
{
    if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') || (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';
        std::cout << '|' << matrix[i][j] << '|';
    }
}
```

do this :

```
for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) // 0 to 8, not 1 to 10
{
    if ((matrix[i][j] != 'R') && (matrix[i][j] != 'O'))
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';             
    }
    std::cout << '|' << matrix[i][j] << '|'; // Should be outside the if if you want to print all the matrix
}
```

instead of this :

```
matrix[column - 1][row - 1] = 'R'; 
std::cout << matrix[column][row] << "\n";
```

do this :

```
matrix[column - 1][row - 1] = 'R';
std::cout << matrix[column-1][row-1] << "\n"; // You will always print the element you changed instead of one not related at all
```